# Removing entries from a 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm doing a university assignment and I'm having some trouble with my Array.

I am building a console based address book application and I need to use a 2D-Array which has the options of adding, removing, or printing the contents of the Array...

I am deleting the current entries by replacing the values with "XXX" -as is required in the brief. I then just hide the "XXX" values when printing to screen.

But once I have 'Deleted' an entry, when it comes to printing the entire Array, anything listed AFTER the entry I tried to delete, does not show up at all, except after adding a new entry.

Could anyone shed some light on why this may be happening?

Comment: Show your code for printing the array.

Comment: Your code looks fine, your error seems to be in another part of your code.

Comment: `goto`....`goto`???? 8-O

Comment: Arrays are typically not the best data construct for performing this situation. If you need the ability to add/remove entries at runtime, the List or Dictionary classes are typically more appropriate. That's not to say it cannot be done but you'll save yourself a lot of time if you have a choice.

Comment: As M.Babcock said, you probably want to work with a more appropriate and flexible collections object to work with this. And as Neil Knight brought up... get that goto out of there! Kick those bad habits while still in Uni. I guarantee it can be done WITHOUT a goto call.

Comment: Haha thanks guys, ill have a look at Lists now, but we haven't even been shown them yet which is why i was hoping to do it this way...

Comment: Oh, and i added the printing Array code too Ash!

Comment: I've jsut been back over the brief, it DOES have to be a 2D Array :(

Comment: How about that `break` in the `if(... == "XXX")` block, should that not be a `continue`?

Comment: OH MY GOD, r_ahlskog you done it!
Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there any reason why the code has been removed from you question without ack an answer? I am wasting my time here.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're deleting the whole column, once the if statement catch a true condition, e.g. if the `address[1, 1] == DeleteName` then your array after the for loop will look like:

```
A00    XXX    A02 ...
A10    XXX    A13 ...
A20    XXX    A23 ...
A30    XXX    A33 ...
...    ...
```

So if you just need to delete an entry you will need two loops like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(int j =0;j < 5; j++)
    {
       if (Address[i, j] == DeleteName)
       {
           Address[i, j] = "XXX";
           Console.WriteLine("Contact Deleted");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man! But this still seems to present the same problem at the printing stage, where Hiding this entry will stop anything after it printing to screen

Comment: @MarkP You will also need two loops when printing the array

Answer (score 0):

Also, in your case 3 it looks like you're missing the { } after your else statement

```
else
{
    FName = Address[i, 0]; 
    LName = Address[i, 1]; 
    Number = Address[i, 2]; 
    Road = Address[i, 3]; 
    Town = Address[i, 4]; 
    Console.WriteLine(LName +", " + FName + " - "+ Number + ", " + Road+", " + Town); 
}
```